# How do you pass the index of iteration of {{#each}}?

Tags: ember.js

I have a grid of objects to display. Each row of the grid displays 4 objects. Depending on where an object is in the grid I want certain classes to be on the elements of the objects. For example the last object in the grid should have the class "last_in_grid". This calculation depends on the index of the object in an array.

My template looks like:

```
{{#each row in objects}}
    {{#each object in row}}
        {{view MyApp.MyView objectBinding="object"}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

`MyApp.MyView` needs to know the index in of iteration of the `each` helper.

Ideally I want something like:

```
{{#each row in objects}}
    {{#each object in row}}
        {{view MyApp.MyView objectBinding="object" indexBinding="index_of_each_loop"}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Django's template language can do this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
        blah blah blah
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Is this possible using Ember and Handlebars?

Do I have to write a custom version of `each` to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `{{each}}` helper, You can use `{{collection}}` helper  to get current index of iteration like this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/secretlm/67GQb/73/

HTML:

```
{{#collection contentBinding="App.peopleController"}}    
    {{#view App.PersonView personBinding="content" indexParentBinding="contentIndex" }}
        <td>{{indexParent}}</td> 
        <td>{{person.fullName}}</td>            
    {{/view}}
{{/collection}}
```

Javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName') 
});

App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [App.Person.create({ firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz" }),
    App.Person.create({ firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Dale" })]
});

App.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    indexParent: null    
});​
```

Comment: I used this version because it is a little simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a CollectionView the items/views of that collection can query it and see if they are the last item.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qKXJt/138/

ArrayControllers are just proxies to their content, which is an Ember Array. This means you get all the goodies that come with Enumerable, Array, MutableArray, and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to nest CollectionViews so that an inner CollectionView represents a row and an outer CollectionView represents a grid?

Comment: You could, however what you are describing sounds like a table. You would use a CollectionView to represent the table/grid, and the itemViews would represent the rows. Collection views are just container views, so they can be nested however many times you need them to be.